# Getting 'ReferenceError: not defined' when using import/export modules

Tags: javascript

I've got and exportUserList.js, importUserList.js and the main.js files. The main.js file contains already defined 2 variables which I want to log to the console and I also want to log the imported user variable from the main.js file. But I keep on receiving 'user not defined'. I've used the suggested window option, but it is not passing on the variable. Can this be corrected?

this is the html:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" />
       <title></title>

   <style>
</style>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="module" src="/importUserList.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
       
   </body>
```

this is the export exportUserList.js :

```
export const user = 'first user'
```

this is the import importUserList.js :

```
import {user} from './exportList.js'

console.log(user)

window.user = user
```

and this is the main.js:

```
let names = 'mark'
let numbers = 10

console.log(names)
console.log(numbers)

console.log(user)
```

Comment: Why are you exposing `user` as a global and using it in non-module code?

Comment: Also note that under HTML5 rules all scripts are plain JS unless typed otherwise, so while that module needs `type="module"`, the script element for main does not needs `type="text/javascript"`. However, also note that this is not how you use modules, so you're going to have to rewrite those lines anyway (see answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: `defer` your main script, because modules defer by default, and so because your main script doesn't it gets runs before the module has.

However, that's the bad option, and you shouldn't put that into practice because that keeps you using modules in completely the wrong way. Never do that.

The much better solution is to make your `main.js` a module and then tell it to import what it needs in order to run. You don't load modules only to bind their data onto globalThis (`window` in this case), the whole point of modules is to keep code contained, so that whatever needs a module's exports, can just import that as needed. You use modules to *not* pollute the global scope =)

So: remove that `importUserList.js` and instead put the import in your main script:

```js
import {user} from './exportList.js'

let names = 'mark'
let numbers = 10

console.log(names)
console.log(numbers)
console.log(user)
```

And then load your main script as a module with:

```html
<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
```

And then of course remember that modules [always load deferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer).

Basically: if you're using modules, use modules "all the way down".

Comment: Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Thanks for your help. The defer did the job. And thanks for the advice with modules.

Comment: While it does the job, it's also _incredibly bad JS programming_ so don't use that option. Go with the second option. _Never_ use a module to import data only to bind it to `window` for other scripts: those scripts should import. And if that means multiple scripts all have imports for the same thing: good, that's how it supposed to work.

Comment: Yes, followed through with the 2nd option. The better option ;)