# getAuth defined in module cannot be used. getAuth not defined

Tags: html, web-applications, firebase-authentication

Hi i have imported getAuth in   but when I try to use getAuth in the body it errors "Uncaught ReferenceError: getAuth is not defined"

error on this line `const auth = getAuth();` in function `SignIn`

how can I resolve this please

this is the project

```
<html>
<head>
  <!--jquery, bootstrap css, firebase-->

  <!--jquery-->
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.2.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-2krYZKh//PcchRtd+H+VyyQoZ/e3EcrkxhM8ycwASPA="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

  <!--bootstrap-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-analytics.js";
    import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-auth.js';
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xx",
      authDomain: "xx-22.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "xx-22",
      storageBucket: "xx-22.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "222",
      appId: "1:22:web:ccxxx",
      measurementId: "G-cccc"
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--login form-->
  <div class="container" id="login-form">
    <div class="well">
      <form>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="name@example.com">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="inputPassword" class="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="password">
        </div>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
          <button type="button" id="sign-in-button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
        </div>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
          <button type="button" id="create-newuser-button" class="btn btn-warning">Create new account</button>
        </div>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
          <button type="button" id="google-login-button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in with Google</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--add hero form-->
  <div class="container" id="login-form">
    <div class="well">
      <form>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="inputHeroname" class="form-label">Hero name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputHeroName" placeholder="hero name">
        </div>
        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
          <button type="button" id="create-newhero-button" class="btn btn-primary">reate new hero</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--scripts-->
  <script>
    $("#create-newuser-button").click(function() {
      var email = $("inputEmail").val()
      var password = $("inputPassword").val()
      console.log("new user = " + email + " password - " + password)
      SignIn(email, password)
    }); 
  
    function SignIn(email, password) {
      const auth = getAuth(); //error here
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in 
          const user = userCredential.user;
          // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(error)
          // ..
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

your help ins much appreciated

thanks
R

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69165167/getting-referenceerror-not-defined-when-using-import-export-modules) it seems that your script block with the `getAuth` call runs before the `import`, as module imports are deferred by default. So either defer the inline script block too or (as suggested in the link) put the script block in its own file and import that as a module too.